# Unit test for django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have medium knowledge for unit testing in django. Can someone help me with a unit test?

I have an API like so:

```
elif request.method == "POST":
    note = json.loads(request.body)['note']
    note_objs = Notes.objects.filter(client_user=client_user, expert_user=expert_user)
    if not note_objs:
        note_obj = Notes()
    else:
        note_obj = note_objs[0]
        note_obj.client_user = client_user
        note_obj.expert_user = expert_user
        note_obj.notes = note
        note_obj.save()
        return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': True,
            'note': note_obj.notes,
        })
```

And the unit test like this:

```
# POST note
    data = {
        "note": "testnotes",
    }
    resp = self.api_client.post(self._get_note(client_user), data=data, format='json',
    authentication=self.get_credentials(expert_user))
    self.assertHttpOK(resp)
    json_resp = self.deserialize(resp)
    self.assertEquals(json_resp.get('note'), 'testnotes')
    self.assertEquals(json_resp['success'], True)
```

It is running OK. I want to know how to unit test with the if and else from the API snippet.

Regards

Comment: Well your IF/ELSE doesn't seem to depend on the contents of the http post. so django test client isn't what you should be using.

Comment: I got rid of the if/else and used 2 test cases instead.